# SQL Server - DeploymentContributorFilterer - Ignore all schemes except one

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, dacpac

I am try to deploy a set of tools to various DB's. The best way I could think of doing this is during the release process of a given DB to have two tasks. One task deploys the base dacpac to a DB then having a second task that deploys the tools Dacpac to the same DB as the first task. I know DeploymentContributorFilterer you can pass IgnoreSchema("SchemaName") but can it be used to Ignore all schemas that are not "tools" for example.

Or is there another tool that can help releasing several Dacpacs to one DB but only Create, Modify, Drop Items with the "tools" schema.

I would like to keep the "tools" in a separate project / repo, and create a process that you can easily add these tools to any DB required.

Comment: If there are no "tools" in other dacpacs then `/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=false` could do. So deploying tools would be able only to add or alter objects. Although you will still need to exclude "tools" by DeploymentContributorFilterer so original dacpacs wouldn't drop all the tools during deployment. Perhaps your tools could be a separate database or a CLR dll.

Comment: I found a way to do it using  DeploymentContributorFilterer when using schema filtering you can just a !(SCHEMA) and it will ignore all schemas that are not in the brackets.